# how to detect IEEE-1284 Controller as COM port

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have a very old balance measurement device that has parallel ports. when I connect it to my PC which has windows 7 it does not get detected, so I used a USB to serial cable and now in device manager it gets detected as USB Printing Support. I want to send commands to it with c# using SerialPort class and for that I need it to be detected as COM port. 
Is there any way to force it to get detected as COM port?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The static method [GetPortNames()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.getportnames%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the SerialPort class will return an array of type string with all detected serial ports available on your computer.  To communicate with your device you need to create a new instance of the SerialPort class with all the proper port settings and then open the serial port.  If it is plugged into the correct port you will then be able to send and receive messages with your device.  [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is more documentation on how it works.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but the problem is it gets detected as usb port. if it got detected as COM port I could send commands to it.

Comment: If you are using a USB to RS232 converter it should show up as a serial port (Com port) when the GetPortNames() method is called.  Are you sure it has been installed correctly?  It may show up as a usb device but it should also appear as a com port.  Does it show up in your device manager as a com port?  What is the brand and model number of the USB to RS232 converter?

Comment: sorry for the late response. we tried a new device and it worked. thanks anyways.

Comment: I'm fighting with the same problem. Is there any solution found?

Comment: The following link explains how to fix this problem for a Prolific USB serial adapter by updating its driver.  You may be able to apply this same approach to whatever brand adapter you are using.  https://recoverit.wondershare.com/usbs-tips/fix-prolific-usb-not-working.html  Also, it may help to clear all unused serial ports on your computer as shown here.  https://www.digi.com/support/knowledge-base/how-to-remove-unused-com-ports-for-re-assignment-w